# How to parameterize generic Class before instantiation?

Tags: java, generics

I am loading the db-driver based on command line parameters like this:

```
Class driverClass = null;
try {
    driverClass = Class.forName(dbDriver);
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Print error message here
}
```

Later I call `driverClass.newInstance()`.

How can I avoid the message

> Class is a raw type. References to generic type `Class<T>` should be parameterized

If I try `Class<Driver>` the Class.forName part complains about a type mismatch:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Class<capture#1-of ?>` to
>   `Class<Driver>`

This is weird, how can I parameterize the Class in the first line correctly?

Comment: The `class` is not influenced by the generic paramter, so you do not need it when calling `forName()`. Have you tried to parameterize when calling `newInstance()`?

Comment: Why are you using `forName` in the first place? That's not the right way to load a database driver.

Comment: @LewBloch well, I thought this was the right way to do it, how can I do it better?

Comment: Study the documentation. The JDBC Tutorial should help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try Class the Class.forName part complains about a type mismatch

Well if you know the class name at compile time, why initialise the class using `forName`, just do this:

```
Class<Driver> driverClass = Driver.class;
```

If you don't know the class name at compile time, you can simply put a `?` as the type parameter:

```
Class<?> driverClass = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do now know the exact class name, you can specify `?` as a type meaning any class that extends `Object`:

```
Class<?> driverClass = Class.forName(dbDriver);
```

Comment: This does not really take care of the problem since you still instantiate a raw-type. Furthermore, code-only answers are discouraged. Please explain your solution.